# Spark - No Space Left on device error

Tags: unix, apache-spark

I am getting the below error . The Spark_local_dir has been set and has enough space and inodes left.

```
 java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:58)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.dumpOutput(SnappyOutputStream.java:294)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.compressInput(SnappyOutputStream.java:306)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.rawWrite(SnappyOutputStream.java:245)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.write(SnappyOutputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyOutputStreamWrapper.write(CompressionCodec.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ChainedBuffer.read(ChainedBuffer.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.PartitionedSerializedPairBuffer$$anon$2.writeNext(PartitionedSerializedPairBuffer.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.writePartitionedFile(ExternalSorter.scala:757)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


cat spark-env.sh |grep -i local
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/var/log/hadoop/spark
```

disk usage
    df -h /var/log/hadoop/spark
    Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/meta  200G  1.1G  199G   1% /var/log/hadoop

inodes
    df -i /var/log/hadoop/spark
    Filesystem                     Inodes IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/meta 209711104   185 209710919    1% /var/log/hadoop

Comment: This means it is writing somewhere you don't expect.

Comment: Or some temporary space is full. Look at other filesystems to see if one is near capacity.   Or you're writing a LOT more data than you intended.

Comment: "and has enough space" well apparently it doesn't :-) You'll need to show us your config, what exactly you're doing and with how much data.

Comment: Assuming you are running on Unix: Please execute "df -h" and provide the the output of the command.

Comment: Config and disk usage details are added to question. @Peter even i suspect the data is being written somewhere i didnt expect and need to know where it is. anyone shedding some light on this would be a life saver

Comment: @user727272 I would look at the disk usage of all your filesystems and see which one might be full.

Comment: @user727272 which scheduler are you using? Standalone, YARN or Mesos?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same issue. To resolve it, I first checked my hdfs disk usage by running `hdfs dfsadmin -report`.

The `Non DFS Used` column was above 250 GB. This implied that my logs or tmp or intermediate data was consuming too much space.

After running `du -lh | grep G` from `root` folder I figured that `spark/work` was consuming over 200 GB.

After looking at the folders inside `spark/work` I understood that by mistake I forgot to uncomment `System.out.println` statement and hence the logs were consuming high space.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running YARN in `yarn-cluster` mode then the local dirs used by both Spark executors and driver will be taken from YARN config (`yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs`). `spark.local.dir` and your env variable will be ignored.

If you're running YARN in `yarn-client` mode then the executors will use the local dirs configured the in the YARN config again but the driver will use the one you specified in your env variable because in that mode the driver is not ran on the YARN cluster.

So try setting that config.

You can find a bit more information [in the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties)

And there's even a whole section on [running spark on yarn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check how many inodes were used by hadoop. If they all have gone, the generic error would be the same, no space left, while there is still a space.